# I am One Out of Fourteen

Tags: outer-space

> I tried twice to be one of 14 though it was not to be
>
> My first was normal and no ones tragedy
>
> the second was definitely someone's mistake
>
> as the very air I breathed was enough to cause a break.

Who am I and what did I fail to do?

Comment: 1st question here, so please be kind. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are:

> Fred Wallace Haise Junior
>  12 people have walked on the moon, but it would have been 14 (including you) if Apollo 13 had not run into problems (no-one's mistake)
>  You were due to go to the moon again on Apollo 19 but this was cancelled - this was someone's mistake.